# When are two metrics related by a coordinate transformation?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Let there be two metrics $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ and $\tilde g_{\mu\nu}(x)$. How can I decide if there exists a coordinate transformation $y^\mu(x)$ such that $\tilde g_{\mu\nu}(y(x))=\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial y^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial y^\nu}g_{\alpha\beta}(x)$?

Comment: This is simply a set of partial differential equations in $x$